# Run isolated JavaScript commands in VS Code (not current file)

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to run individual commands in VS Code but not the whole file. I do work on client websites where a lot of my code will not run in a standard debugger or in the Quokka extension because it relies on the page that I am working on (and running in the debugger does not perfectly emulate how my code will run. But sometimes I like to run a few lines of code or a single function separately to make sure I have it set right without having to copy my code over to the online platform used to execute it and load up a preview link. Normally what I like to do is open a new chrome tab at `about:blank` and use the dev console there to paste in my code and this is my "playground" of sorts. Is there any form of active JS engine that I can do this in without having to save these lines to a new file and run the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking all these things in VS code I think it will be a bit hard because of this.

to run JS code snippet VS code must have JS engine like same for PHP its compiler or same for any other language and adding these compilers in IED will again make these IEDs fat and CPU costly.

BUT Still, you can do one thing if you have a node js installed open Terminal outside or inside the  VS code.
and type

```
$node
```

This will open a JS playground. Where you can execute js code snippets

[image]

but here you will not be able to access  DOM, WINDOW object, etc.

In case you found any plugin which executes js code in VS CODE with DOM, window please let me know.

Comment: This is perfect. I knew about the console but didn't even think about running node inside of it. Not the most copy & paste friendly for multiple lines because it seems to run each line as it's pasted in. But this is not a huge deal to work around. Thanks a ton!